# ImportError: cannot import name 'db' from [package_name]

Tags: python, flask, package, flask-sqlalchemy, importerror

I have a complicated code structure. The Project folder has a mother package that holds two more child package. I need to import a SQLAlchemy instance, db from the the mother package's **init**.py file to a child packages db_models.py file. the db_models.py holds all the routes that exchanges calls to the database. I have seen other solutions that came up but those didn't solve the problem as mine has multiple packages. Following is the hierarchy of my project.

```
FlaskUserAuthentication(project)
    FlaskUserAuthentication(package)=>
        API(package)=>
            __init__.py
            db_models.py
            routes.py(Blueprint)
        Site(package)=>
            __init__.py
            routes.py(Blueprint)
            templates=>
                index.html
                signin.html
                signup.html
        __init__.py
run.py (under project)
```

Under the project folder `FlaskUserAuthentication`, I have a `package` with the same name(`FlaskUserAuthentication`). The following is the code from its `__init__.py` file.

```
from flask import Flask
from FlaskUserAuthentication.API.routes import api
from FlaskUserAuthentication.Site.routes import site
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'

app.register_blueprint(api)
app.register_blueprint(site)
```

Under the two child packages under namely `API` and `Site`, there are `routes.py` files one of which handles the database queries(API/routes.py) and another one renders the views(Site/routes.py). Both of these packages has a Blueprint instance.

The following is the code from `API(package)/routes.py` file-

```
from flask import jsonify, Blueprint, request
from FlaskUserAuthentication.API.db_models import Member

api = Blueprint('api', __name__)

@api.route('/members')
def get_all_members():
    members = Member.query.all()
    return jsonify({'response': 'This will return the members from the sqlite database'})
```

However at the second line, where I am trying to import the `SQLAlchemy` model class, `Member`, I am getting some error which doesn't refer to that line but it was okay before I added that line, so I realized this was it. The following is the error I am getting -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\FlaskUserAuthentication\run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from FlaskUserAuthentication import app
  File "F:\FlaskUserAuthentication\FlaskUserAuthentication\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from FlaskUserAuthentication.API.routes import api
  File "F:\FlaskUserAuthentication\FlaskUserAuthentication\API\routes.py", line 2, in <module>
    from FlaskUserAuthentication.API.db_models import Member
  File "F:\FlaskUserAuthentication\FlaskUserAuthentication\API\db_models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from FlaskUserAuthentication import db
ImportError: cannot import name 'db' from 'FlaskUserAuthentication' (F:\FlaskUserAuthentication\FlaskUserAuthentication\__init__.py)
```

The following code is from the API/db_model.py file-

```
from FlaskUserAuthentication import db
from datetime import datetime

class Member(db.Model):
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column('user_name', db.String(100), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column('email', db.String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column('password', db.String(100), nullable=False, unique=False)
```

However, If I comment out the `from FlaskUserAuthentication.API.db_models import Member`, under the API/routes.py file, I don't get this error.

I realized it must be a circular import issue but can anyone please explain me how to avoid such error?

How can I import my db_model classes in my routes.py file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are importing `db` (in `API/db_model.py`) before it's initialized. The quick and dirty solution might be to import `api` *after* you initialize the `db` object in the top level `__init__.py`.

```py
from flask import Flask
from FlaskUserAuthentication.Site.routes import site
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'

from FlaskUserAuthentication.API.routes import api
```

I suggest you use the app factory pattern, however, as your application grows in complexity.